# Disable automatic layout change on Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout

I've made an app, I've tested it and it was fine on my phone. But... when I gave the .apk to someone else whose phone language is RTL the whole layout broke and it messed up everything.

My question is - How can I force my app to use only LTR and disable the auto layout change which breaks my whole app design?

Answer (score 40):

In your manifest file and inside the application tag add these two lines.

```
<manifest>
    <application
        .
        .
        .
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl" //(replace libraries' Rtl support with ours)
        >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Note: (about second line)
Some libraries have support Rtl in their manifest file so if you want to use those libraries you must replace their manifest line of code with yours.

Comment: Solved my problem too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

Android 4.2 added full native support for RTL layouts. To take advantage of RTL layout mirroring, simply make the following changes to your app:

- Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring.
  Specifically, add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the 
  element in your manifest file.
- Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new
  "start/end" equivalents. If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2
  (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then
  you should use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For
  example, `android:paddingLeft` should become `android:paddingStart`. If
  you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the
  app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you
  should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For
  example, you’d use both `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingStart`.

For more precise control over your app UI in both LTR and RTL mode, Android 4.2 includes the following new APIs to help manage View components:

- android:layoutDirection — attribute for setting the direction of a
  component's layout.
- android:textDirection — attribute for setting the
  direction of a component's text.
- android:textAlignment — attribute
  for setting the alignment of a component's text.
- getLayoutDirectionFromLocale() — method for getting the
  Locale-specified direction

[-- *Source & Credits* --](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

Comment: I've wanted to disable the RTL, thanks anyway, the problem WAS this stupid line which seems to be added automatically be Eclipse/AS, just changed its value to false and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following to the manifest

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add something like this in your App Theme Style:

```
<item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
or
<item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

For React Native adding the following line in the manifest file was enough:

```
//  android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.kidspodmobileclient">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:supportsRtl="false" // <== add this line here
```

It would be like the following screenshot:

[image]

RN version: 0.68.2