# How to prevent layout changes based on phone's language?

Tags: android, layout

I know that `android:supportsRtl="true"` method fits the app to the screen in different sizes. But if a phone has a language which is right-to-left instead of left-to-right, like Persian the buttons or text views, specially if they are in rows, will be right-to-left.

How can I prevent app's layout's changing based on language?

Or keep it in English language in all phones?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450489/disable-automatic-layout-change-on-android

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120673/change-locale-but-keep-left-to-right-and-other-phone-orientations

Comment: thanks. adding `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to my layouts fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

In your `manifest.xml`, inside the application tag add this line.

```
<application
 ...
    android:supportsRtl="false"
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Set all the strings in your resources with `translatable=false` in your strings definitions (as shown [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings)) and set `supportsRtl=false`, so that your app will never attempt to adapt to the phone conditions. 

For language, another strategy could be simply to not provide any translation for the resources: this way the system cannot use layout resources relative to your phone language and region, simply because there aren't any.

Comment: but my `string.xml` file just contains a line and it won't work.its a very simple app bro. setting `supportsRtl` to false will make the app non-translatable and it will be fixed in this case.but it will take the design down. i'm seeking a method which do that without setting `supportsRtl="false",

Comment: Why does `supportsRtl=false` take your design down? Maybe I did not understand your question

Comment: well i think that method is for fitting layout for different sizes. and setting that to false will cause ruining layout.

Comment: `supportsRtl` tells the system how to manage the layout according to the text direction. As you can read here --> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html it essentially generalizes the "left/right" attributes to "start/end". The two are interchangeable and setting the support to false will not ruin the existing layout.

Comment: Yea.you're right. it wont ruin the layout completely. it just changes some text aligns and one of my `EditText`s goes out of the border. i don't know why.Anyway adding  `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to the layouts not the Manifest  fixed it.Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Just remember to mark the solution here, to help others that could have your same problem!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to your layouts and appBar. It can solve your problem.
Adding `android:supportsRtl="false"` to manifest can help you, But it isn't enough.